# Is there a word/expression for the attitude of giving a lot of advice

Tags: vocabulary

In the expression "it feels patronizing", patronizing have the following meaning:

> apparently kind or helpful but betraying a feeling of superiority; condescending.

In a slightly similar context, I wonder if there is another word or expression that describes someone who gives a lot of advice and guidance with honest intentions but in a bothering excess.

Comment: Heh heh.  I must be very careful not to look in the mirror on this one. :^) https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/patronizing

Comment: "Busybody" might fight the bill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options:

- "Stop **backseat driving**, you're driving me crazy!"
- "Stop **pestering** me, you're driving me crazy!"
- "Stop **nagging** me, you're driving me crazy!"

"Pestering" and "nagging" are weaker examples as they don't really suggest that someone has good intentions. Generally speaking, if you're "backseat driving" you have good intentions, but are still being overbearing/not helpful.

Comment: Another way of describing the situation is by labeling the advice as "unsolicited". Speaks less to the intention behind the advice and more to the fact that you didn't want/ask for it.

Comment: @AymaneFihadi Some more: if the person giving advice is in a position of authority, we could talk about "[micromanaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromanagement)." If it's a peer, and you want to emphasize that too many perspectives are unhelpful, there's an idiom "Too many cooks spoil the soup."